# How to make keyboard shortcuts work in detached windows of Android Studio 3?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I've moved Project and Source control tool windows to second monitor. Now, when I'm trying to delete file or rename or smth else with keyboard nothing happens. I have to use context menu. I'm using AS 3.1.2 on Mac. 
How to fix it ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch tool windows from Floating Mode to Windowed Mode :)